# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in if()

Tags: php, syntax

I'm getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

Here is my code (used in a wordpress comment loop)

```
<?php 
if (current_user_can('edit_comment',$comment->comment_ID)) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_edit_comment_link(); ?>" title="Edit Comment">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/edit-link.png"/>
    </a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Why do you have two backticks/backquotes in your code? Did you add those when posting it here?

Comment: Your code looks fine and I think there are some nested `if` and something went wrong with other `if` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php if (current_user_can('edit_comment',$comment->comment_ID)) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_edit_comment_link(); ?>" title="Edit Comment">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/edit-link.png"/>
    </a>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Don't use short tags. Quite big number of servers don't support and it often becomes headache.

Comment: I could also swear i used this code with no success. But it works fine now.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of sticking to one language at a time.  Context switches are confusing.

```
<?php

if (current_user_can('edit_comment',$comment->comment_ID)) {
    printf( "<a href='%s' title='Edit Comment'><img src='%s/images/edit-link.php'/></a>",
      get_edit_comment_link(),
      get_template_directory_uri()
    );
}

?>
```

Though this is personal preference, and I don't see anything technically wrong with the code in your question.

Comment: Ah, hurray, another anonymous downvote.  Look, if you don't like the answer, post a comment saying why.  Downvote it if it's *incorrect* or *misleading*.  Silent sniping is cowardly and pointless.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<?php 
if (current_user_can('edit_comment',$comment->comment_ID)) { 
   echo "<a href=\"get_edit_comment_link()\" title=\"Edit Comment\">
        <img src=\"get_template_directory_uri()/images/edit-link.png\"/>
    </a>";
 } ?>
```

also why not

```
<?php $a=get_edit_comment_link(); $b=get_template_directory_uri();
if (current_user_can('edit_comment',$comment->comment_ID)) {
   echo "<a href=\"$a\" title=\"Edit Comment\">
        <img src=\"$b/images/edit-link.png\"/>
    </a>";
 } ?>
```

Comment: Echoing HTML like this is a nightmare to read, debug and maintain.

Comment: Using <?php ?> multiple times, you use 7 Bytes more each time. It might not be much but imagine a user loading 100 times the pages.

Comment: @Furgas I know I was just being short and easier to understand. You prefer to do this <?php ?> 

I use mostly echo <<< something